# How to read docker command?

Tags: docker

I would like someone to assist me in reading below docker run command

```
docker run --rm \
           --volumes-from myredis \
           -v $PWD/backup:/backup \
           debian \
           cp /data/dump.rdb /backup/
```

I know it dumps redis, and attaching volume from container myredis into cwd backup. As for the rest of the command I am having trouble interpreting it.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you try reading the docs?

Comment: Have you reviewed the output of `docker run --help`?

Comment: Yes, I am just not acquainted with it. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this command is to create a redis's backup you are coping the dump.rdb into the /backup dir on your host.

--rm means remove the container after run, usually it's a good way to clean your env because you can not reuse this container when it finish its work.

debian is the name of the image that you are using.

"cp /data/dump.rdb /backup/" is the command that you are doing inside your container

Comment: yes, but what does --rm means and the rest of the command why I am having debian in the command too. Thanks

Comment: I will do docker run --help to figure it out. It is just I am not accustomed to running --help. I think I should acquaint myself with the help.

Comment: --rm means remove the container after run, usually it's a good way to clean your env because you can not reuse this container when it finish its work.

debian is the name of the image that you are using.

"cp /data/dump.rdb /backup/" is the command that you are doing inside your container

Comment: @GianArb, ...you might add that information into your answer, rather than only having it here in the comments.